# OpenSSH for Windows connection with private key and passphrase

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

I want to switch from Putty to OpenSSH for SSH connections in windows to our servers. I want to use OpenSSH only as client and I have a private key with additional passphrase.

I tried to connect to my server and OpenSSH loads the keyfile, but everytime I enter the passphrase, it seems that it isn't correct.

```
C:\Users\user>ssh -i D:\folder\.ssh\private_key user@host
Enter passphrase for key 'D:\folder\.ssh\private_key':
Enter passphrase for key 'D:\folder\.ssh\private_key':
Enter passphrase for key 'D:\folder\.ssh\private_key':
user@host's password:
```

You can see, my keyfiles are not located in the standard folder. I don't think that this is the problem, so only fyi.

What is the problem? I installed OpenSSH with the standard configuration and changed nothing.

**Edit:**
I also tried a different keyfile on an other server which has also a passphrase: this also doesn't work. Is that maybe a problem in configuration?

Comment: did you convert the key in PuTTY format to standard openSSH format?

Comment: I have also converted the keyfile to the special putty format (.ppk). So I have both files (the normal private keyfile and the ppk). I tried both, but that changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry.

I discovered that I load a very old version. I think I get it from sourceforge and the executables are very outdated (year 2003 to 2004).

You can get a actual version from github: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/. I don't know if this is the official release. It's a bit confusing.